# focus is on another control but pressing enter presses the default button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I want a hyperlink, which currently have focus, to be clicked when I press enter key.

Can somebody help me with the javascript code?

I do have written a code in javascript that actually tries to click a button when focus is on that button -

```
 if ((KeyCode == 13))
                {
                    evt.returnValue=false;
                    evt.cancel = true;
                
                    if((document.activeElement.name != 'btnChangeRep') && 
                        (document.activeElement.name != 'btnSubmitAndOpen') &&  
                        (document.activeElement.name != 'hypTaxID') && document.activeElement.name != 'hypCoTaxID') &&
                        (document.activeElement.name != 'hypFormerRegSearch'))
                {
                        btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
                        if (btn == null)
                    {                       
                            document.getElementById('btnSave').click();                 
                    }
                        else
                    {                   
                            document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();               
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    document.getElementById(document.activeElement.name).click();                   
                }
```

It is working fine in firefox but in IE link is not opening on press of enter anyhow.

Can someone please help me as where I am going wrong

**EDIT** HTML for hyperlink

```
<asp:hyperlink id="hypTaxID" runat="server"></asp:hyperlink>
```

Comment: Do you mean button or link? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Is a hyperlink. I have edited the HTML in my answer.

Comment: Since you are using asp, any reason you aren't doing this in the code-behind and letting asp sort out the client-side javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling click on a link will fire any javascript click events for the link but not always cause the navigation to happen.

In the past I have had to use javascript to do the navigation. You would want something like the following. (I'd also use jquery to simplify it some what)

```
if ((KeyCode == 13))
{
   evt.returnValue=false;
   evt.cancel = true;

   if((document.activeElement.name != 'btnChangeRep') && 
     (document.activeElement.name != 'btnSubmitAndOpen') &&  
     (document.activeElement.name != 'hypTaxID') && 
      document.activeElement.name != 'hypCoTaxID') &&
     (document.activeElement.name != 'hypFormerRegSearch'))
  {
        btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
        if (btn == null)
        {                       
            document.getElementById('btnSave').click();                 
        }
        else
        {                   
             document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();               
        }
  }
  else 
  {  
      /*new code*/
      var link = document.getElementById(document.activeElement.name).getAttribute("href"); 
      document.location.href = link;
  }
}
```

Also make sure that the ID's of your ASP.net elements are what you expect. Webforms are notorious for ID and name mangling.

I would also evaluate why you are not using ASP.net to handle this on the serverside. Using an ASP.net panel lets you set a [default button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) for the panel so that button is clicked the when enter button is pressed.